# Tomcat Java Servlet path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm messing around with Maven/Tomcat/Java in Eclipse. I have made this java servlet, but when I go to localhost:xxxx/myapp/rest I don't get a response on my GET request, I get a 404. I thought if I put the @path to /rest I can send a GET request to the url, but it's not working.
Does anyone know what the issue is? Thank you!

```
@Path("/rest")
public class WorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getOrders() {
        WorldService service = ServiceProvider.getWorldService();
        JsonArrayBuilder jab = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (Country o : service.getAllCountries()) {
            JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            job.add("iso2Code", o.getCode());
            job.add("iso3Code", o.getIso3Code());
            job.add("capital", o.getCapital());
            job.add("continent", o.getContinent());
            job.add("region", o.getRegion());
            job.add("surface", o.getSurface());
            job.add("population", o.getPopulation());
            job.add("government", o.getGovernment());
            job.add("latitude", o.getLatitude());
            job.add("longitude", o.getLongitude());
            jab.add(job);
        }
        JsonArray array = jab.build();
        System.out.println(array);
        return array.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it not working, what do you mean? Do you get 200 OK but no response, request is failing at server or the request is not received by server?

Comment: I get a 404 error. @manu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a servlet, it's a JAX-RS Resource. This will not work "out of the box" within Tomcat, you'll need to deploy a JAX-RS implementation along with it (like Jersey).

A Servlet would look something like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "WorldServlet", urlPatterns = {"/rest"})
public class WorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            ... // your code
            out.println(array.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

So, you really just need to look in to installing a JAX-RS provider. Also, when you do that, odds are high it STILL won't be at `/rest`, because the JAX-RS implementation is normally rooted at some path, so you might end up with something like `/resources/rest`.

That's all configurable of course.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen because your servlet is incapable of converting your POJO to appropriate HTTP response.

Instead of `return array.toString();` 
try `return Response.status(200).entity(array.toString()).build();`

Comment: The method status(200) is undefined for the type Response.

Comment: **What** POJO? The method is returning a `String` which contains JSON.

Comment: Make sure you are using javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@SomeName refer this blog https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-path-uri-matching-example/

Comment: @EJP I am just saying that there needs to be some kind of http message converter which automatically converts the POJO(in this case String) to the desired http response(depending on content-type). Correct me if I am wrong.